# Get maximum values in three or more lists of different lengths

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I need to resize the columns in the Excel datasheet with Python's `xlsxwriter`. For this purpose I've prepared three lists of maximum text lengths in dataframe columns.

```
l1 = [5, 10, 12, 3, 6, 2]
l2 = []
l3 = [6, 9, 11, 5, 4, 4, 8, 7]
```

I need to get the maximum values in these lists so that the resulting list will look like this:

```
common = [6, 10, 12, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7]
```

I know I should write here my own solution, but it's trivial: we should find the list with maximum length, then compare each value with each other list if its length allows that. But is there a more optimal way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are always guaranteed to be positive numbers, you can [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) them using `0` as a `fillvalue`:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> list(map(max, zip_longest(l1, l2, l3, fillvalue=0)))
[6, 10, 12, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7]
```

If there can be negative numbers as well, you can use negative infinity instead of `0`:

```
>>> from math import inf
>>> list(map(max, zip_longest(l1, l2, l3, fillvalue=-inf)))
[6, 10, 12, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7]
```